# How to define env variables before import in jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, jestjs

In my unit test, there is an imported module `import { DeviceFromDb1 } from '../Device'` which is a file related to mongoose schema define.

The reason that makes me run into this question is: in this file, I need to populate data from another database, and this is how I did:

../Device file:

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(
  process.env.MONGODB_URI + '/' + process.env.ADMINDB
);

const adminDbModel = getAdminModel(conn); // this function will return the model I want from the adminDb

// Inside Schema definition, I used 'ref: adminDbModel' to do the populate
```

For unit test, I use MongoMemoryServer. Usually what I do in other unit tests is, open a new MongoMemoryServer and set the uri of it as the Env variable MONGO_URI. However, this approach doesn't work in this unit test as when the module is imported, both MONGODB_URI and ADMINDB are undefined so `mongoose.createConnection` throw an error "MongoParseError: Invalid connection string "undefined/undefined"". It turns out that this module is loaded before my unit test starts(earlier than beforeEach, beforeAll).

Approach I tried:

1. setupFiles
   By predefining ENV in setupFiles, I could set ENV value and it works if I want to console.log(process.env.ADMINDB) in ../Device.ts. However, MONGODB_URI is a dynamic value which will not be known until a new MongoMemoryServer is created.
2. Top-level `await`
   I tried to run async/await(get a new MongoMemoryServer and set the ENV) before `import { DeviceFromDb1 } from '../Device'` but doesn't help either.

I hope you can give me some hint if there is anyway to define the ENV before the module is loaded, or if I'm using the populate in a wrong way(I can get the result that I want by calling the endpoint so I assume this approach is ok)

Comment: Start `MongoMemoryServer` in your `setupFiles` file.

Comment: @hoangdv Yes, this approach solves the problem to some extent. But the problem is, for some unit test, I used `MongoMemoryReplSet` instead of `MongoMemoryServer`. Is there anyway to make it more dynamic?